# QscrollArea no muestra verticalSlider

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy realizando una ventana que muestre los mensaje en un `QScrollArea` sin embargo el problema que tengo es que al momento de que se llena la `QScrollArea` no muestra el `slidervertical` y solo encima los widgets sin mostrar el slider

Anexo una imagen de ejemplo:

Lo que espero obtener es poder añadir widget al scrollArea indefinidamente y que pueda ir visualizándolos utilizando el slider

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QWidget,QVBoxLayout
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db,credentials
from PyQt5 import uic,QtCore

class Main(QMainWindow):
    datos = ""
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("scrol.ui",self)

        self.FirebaseLogin()
        self.boton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.pushdata())

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollArea)
        self.layout.addStretch()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)



    def FirebaseLogin(self):
        cred = credentials.Certificate("accesFire.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
            'databaseURL':'https://exe-tablas.firebaseio.com/'
        })
        firebase_admin.db.reference("/Chat").listen(self.Escucha)

    def pushdata(self):
        ref = db.reference("/")
        ref_pushed = ref.child("Chat")
        ref_pushed.push({
            "hola":"hola"
        })
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setStyleSheet("Background:red;")
        self.label.setText(self.datos)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)


    def Escucha(self,event):
        print(event.data)
        self.datos = str(event.data)


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes **asignar el layout al widget contenedor que está dentro de tu `ScrollArea`**:

```
self.widget = QWidget(self)
self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)      # <<<<<<<<<
self.layout.addStretch()
self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

Pasar el widget al constructor del layout es equivalente a hacer `widget.setLayout(layout_instance)`.

Por cierto, no uses una función anónima para llamar a un slot sin argumentos, es innecesario e ineficiente.

```
from firebase_admin import db,credentials
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore

class Main(QMainWindow):
    datos = ""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("scrol.ui", self)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.pushdata)
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.layout.addStretch()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

    def firebase_login(self):
        cred = credentials.Certificate("accesFire.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
            'databaseURL':'https://exe-tablas.firebaseio.com/'
        })
        firebase_admin.db.reference("/Chat").listen(self.escucha)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def pushdata(self):
        ref = db.reference("/")
        ref_pushed = ref.child("Chat")
        ref_pushed.push({
            "hola": "hola"
        })
        label = QLabel()
        label.setStyleSheet("Background:red;")
        label.setText(self.datos)
        self.layout.addWidget(label)

    def escucha(self, event):
        print(event.data)
        self.datos = str(event.data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```